# Breeze predicate: column = null vs column IS NULL

Tags: sql, null, breeze, predicate

Can breeze predicate test for null column? SQL test for null in two ways: `columnname = null` and `columnname IS NULL`, which generate different results. I have a breeze predicate set as

```
new breeze.Predicate("columnname", "==", null)
```

Using EF6 interceptors, I am able to view the sql query used and the predicate is evaluated as `columnname = null`. How do I set a predicate such that the sql query generated will be `columnname IS NULL`

Comment: Is `columnname = null` ever true?

Comment: @jarlh no. it is always false

Comment: Thanks. (It was a leading question... To explain why OP gets different results...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the docs?
http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/Predicate.html#method_ Predicate

One of the examples

```
var p2 = new Predicate("Region", FilterQueryOp.Equals, null);
```

More docs, with your answer, on FilterQueryOp: 
http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/FilterQueryOp.html#property_Equals

This shows that you can do ==  fine for null equality.
It also shows that there is no "IS NULL" option, so to answer your question, no you can not do "is null" from the breeze client side predicate.

However, you should note that this is client side, I believe you will need to evaluate your server side code more to find out where it is processing the breeze request and transforming it into SQL.

Comment: You were right. I needed to set up the column on the server side as nullable.